RecordId Undefined In LWC
I'm trying to perform simple update on record with LWC button. But i can't get record id.
Here's full code
import {api, LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
import {getRecord, updateRecord} from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import {ShowToastEvent} from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import {refreshApex} from "@salesforce/apex";
import NOTIFICATION_TEXT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Notification_Text__c';
import ID_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Case.Id";

const CASE_FIELDS = [
    ID_FIELD, NOTIFICATION_TEXT_FIELD
]

export default class ClearNotifications extends LightningElement {

    disabledClearNotification = false;
    @api recordId;

    clearNotification(){
        const fields = {};
        console.log(this.recordId);
        fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.recordId;
        fields[NOTIFICATION_TEXT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = '';
        console.log(fields);
        this.disabledClearNotification = true;
        const recordInput = { fields };

        updateRecord(recordInput)
            .then(() => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: "Success",
                        message: "Notification Cleared",
                        variant: "success",
                    }),
                );
                // Display fresh data in the form
                this.disabledClearNotification = false;
                return refreshApex(this.case);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.disabledClearNotification = false;
                console.log(error);
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: "Error creating record",
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: "error",
                    }),
                );
            });
    }
}

Meta file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>59.0</apiVersion>
    <description>Clear Notifications</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Clear Notifications</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

HTML:
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-text-align_center">
                <lightning-button label="Clear Notifications" disabled={disabledClearNotification} slot="" onclick={clearNotification}></lightning-button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

FINAL JS:
import {api, LightningElement} from 'lwc';
import {updateRecord} from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import {ShowToastEvent} from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import {refreshApex} from "@salesforce/apex";
import NOTIFICATION_TEXT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Notification_Text__c';
import ID_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Case.Id";

export default class ClearNotifications extends LightningElement {

    disabledClearNotification = false;
    @api recordId;

    clearNotification(){
        const fields = {};
        fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.recordId;
        fields[NOTIFICATION_TEXT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = '';
        this.disabledClearNotification = true;
        const recordInput = { fields };

        updateRecord(recordInput)
            .then(() => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: "Success",
                        message: "Notification Cleared",
                        variant: "success",
                    }),
                );
                // Display fresh data in the form
                this.disabledClearNotification = false;
                return refreshApex(this.case);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.disabledClearNotification = false;
                console.log(error);
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: "Error creating record",
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: "error",
                    }),
                );
            });
    }
}


are you clicking the button instantly? Try adding a renderedCallback method to your javascript and console.log the recordId

Still undefined :/ after loging in renderedCallbcack, also in previous test i have waited too.

Suggestion: Create an extremely simple LWC exposing a recordId (see e.g. [here])(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-record-context.html) and make sure it works. Bit by bit add your required features to it, after each step making sure it still works - and see when it stops to do so. Based on the code presented here, it won't take you very long until you know what's wrong.

I have no idea what happend, i follow your advice by commenting whole function and html then console log in connected callback and it worked. Then i uncommented html and clearNotification function and... it works!
Thank you :D

Glad I was able to help :-)

I guess you had an error in the code that was preventing deployment, which got fixed when you were trying stuff out as suggested by Felix.

But i didn't receive any error, also i have edited post and added final version which is working
